# Ubuntu One not connecting to the cloud service

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one

I have subscribed to Ubuntu One recently.

On the [account page](https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/) I do see the machine I am using ( running Lucid Lynx 10.04).

But on my loal machine the tab "Ubuntu One Preferences" remains desperatly lifeless.

- The Account tab is only listing **Unknown**
- The Device tab returns to **Disconnected** after trying to connect for 3/5 minutes.

Do you know what should I check so as to find the trouble ?
The [TroubleShooter](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/ubuntuone) hasnt happened to be uselful for now.

I am gonna try the command lines for Ubuntu One, not tried yet, but if you have any ideas :-)

Comment: After having tried to install the command line package, which was already installed ;-)... Command lines were inoperative, so I basically didnt modify anything... But after ten minutes, then like magically, all was synchronized. Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably will need to use the command line tools, 'u1sdtool' in this case. Start with the following.

## For connecting..

> u1sdtool -c

## For checking that you are connected..

> u1sdtool --status

## Further command for understanding what is going on..

> u1sdtool --waiting-content
>
> u1sdtool --waiting-metadata
>
> u1sdtool --current-transfers

If it still does not work check the logfiles under '~/.cache/ubuntuone/log'. Historically problems with individual files could  stop all syncing. From my experience  this is not so much an problem any more. After connecting (again) you might experience that the machine get quite busy for a while while the sync-daemon recalulate checksums for files to see that they have not changed.

Comment: oh many thanx, I didn't figure out that I was mistaking ulsdtool with u1sdtool... grrr 1/l... Finally it worked without it, but I am sure somedays I will need these commands.